# After update tfs version couldn't connect tfs from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

We update our tfs version from 2013 to 2017. After update tfs version couldn't connect tfs from visual studio.

Everytime i am getting `"You are not authorized to access http://tfs.youraddress.com/tfs"`

but i can connect from browser with same credentials.

I deleted generic tfs credentials from "Credential Manager" and add again but i didn't work.

I tried to type ipconfig / flushdns to cmd and it didn't work.

I tried to delete TeamExplorer.config from "C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_674a43b7\Team Explorer" and i didn't work.

By the way my computer on business domain. I think theres is something wrong with this domain but i can't figure out what can i do.

Comment: Can you connect to TFS on other client machines which installed VS?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a Visual Studio 2017 credential cached token issue. You could try below ways to clear cache:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.

   (By default it should be `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\.IdentityService`)

There are some identity related caching going on in there, deleting the folder will force the identity system to rebuild its cache.

- Also Clear TFS  related caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team
  Foundation\x.0\Cache`
- Run Visual Studio as another user:

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

  `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`

  Enter the user possword, then `Team Explorer` > `Manage Connections`

If the issue still exists, also take a look at this [blog](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2017/04/vs2017-unable-to-login-failed-to-refresh-access-token/) for more ways.

Comment: @Emre BEGEN Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?